# How to create indexes using Hibernate for PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am using Hibernate as the ORM tool with PostgreSQL. For some of the entities in the project Model, I would like to create Indexes for faster lookup. As I read, I found out it is possible to create indexes using Hibernate. Unfortunately, I am not having much luck. I only tried to create it on one Model class, but when I check in PGAdmin, I cannot see any index for that table.

When I try giving the @Index parameter to the @Table annotation, I get error. Can anyone tell me how I can annotate columns and entire table for auto-indexing by Hibernate. Thanks a lot.

Online User model : // This class I just used for testing

```
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;

import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name="onlineusers" )
@Indexed(index = "onlineuserindex")
public class OnlineUsers {

  @Id
    @Column(name="onlineuserid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "online_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "online_gen",sequenceName = "online_seq")
    private int onlineUserId;


    @Column(name = "onlineusername")
    private String personName;
}
```

Please note, when I try something like this below :

```
@Indexed(index = "usernameindex");
@Column(name="username");
private String userName;
```

I get an error, @Indexed not applicatble to a field.

POM.xml :

```
 <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.6.RELEASE </org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.9.Final</hibernate.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

  <!-- Hibernate search dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
-->
```

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Indexed` annotation from `Hibernate Search` is only applicable to types. So you cannot use those on attributes.

Reading your question, it seems that you want to add a database index to the table? if so then you have to use [Index Annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Unfortunately whenever I search on Google, I am getting result back relevant to Hibernate-search. You documentation points me to Javadocs, and nothing specific in it, which makes it rather difficult to find. Can you please give some example or the actual API/method I would require.

Comment: I came up to the same link, to be honest, I really dont know what to do.

Comment: The @Index column is used to annotate a field which you want the index to be created. So if you want a database index to be created on the field username then you have to annotate the field. Optionally you can specify a name. Here is an example from Hibernate docs - http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2041

Comment: Multiple columns can also be used to create the index(usually at the type level) with the @Table annotation. For ex: @org.hibernate.annotations.Table(
        indexes = {@Index(name = "idx", columnNames = {"id_1", "Id2"}}) At the field level you can use something like this -  @Index(name = "idx_1")
    private User user1;

Comment: Thanks, Your answer bought me closer, I am able to user @Index from hibernate-annotations on Field(Which IDE complains is deprecated), but when I use it on Entity, it says it is expecting a JPA annotation, but got Hibernate Annotation. Any idea why?  I used it like this @Table(name="onlineuser", indexes){and stuff inside this.}).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [@Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Index.html) JPA annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "onlineusers",
    indexes = {
        @Index(name = "usernameindex",  columnList="username", unique = true)   
    }
)
public class OnlineUsers {
   ...
}
```

This is only applied if you use the automatic `hbmddl` schema generation. If the database schema is generated externally (e.g. like when using [Flyway](https://vladmihalcea.com/flyway-database-schema-migrations/)), then this annotation won't have any effect.

When you delegate the database schema generation to an external process (a database migration tool or a manual script update procedure), then you need to include the indexes in the migration scripts.

So, you either generate the whole schema with Hibernate (which is [not even recommended for production systems](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-integration-testing-strategies/)) or you rely on a database migration framework (e.g. Flyway) and the indexes are simply included in an incremental schema update script.

Comment: Thanks, but why am I not able to see the indexes created in PGadmin? But when I use @Index from Hibernate on field, I can see them in Pgadmin.

Comment: I assume you generate your database schema with hbmddl, right?

Comment: No, By myself. I wrote the database table code myself and executed it in SQL console.

Comment: I think I will stick to field Indexes which are atleast getting generated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If those are generated, it means you use `hbmlddl=update`, otherwise Hibernate cannot update your schema. Even so, I don;t see how it can make a diff, since that feature is used to update a Hibernate generated schema anyway. So, there is something missing from your question, if you say it's working.

Comment: Yes, I have hbmlddl=update as auto. I read that it was necessary to generate the indexes.

Comment: I wonder why hibernate doesn't just allow @Index on the column definition?

Comment: Hibernate has an [@Index annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2041) that can be applied on @Column too. It's just that it got deprecated in favor of the JPA-way.